React Native IAP: Unable to detect subscription created in App Store Connect
I'm experiencing an issue with React Native IAP where I can't detect a subscription that was created in Apple Store Connect for my application. I need expert assistance to resolve this problem.
Here are the details:

I've set up a subscription product in App Store Connect for my React Native app.
I'm using the react-native-iap library to handle in-app purchases.
The subscription appears to be configured correctly in App Store Connect.
When trying to retrieve the subscription details in my app, it's not being detected.

Here's a simplified version of my code:
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Alert} from 'react-native';

import {custom} from '../custom';
import {theme} from '../constants';
import {components} from '../components';
import {utils} from '../utils';
import {hooks} from '../hooks';
import { endConnection, getSubscriptions, initConnection } from 'react-native-iap';

const SUBSCRIPTION_SKU = 'com.sub.test';

const Prenium: React.FC = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [subscriptionInfo, setSubscriptionInfo] = useState<any>(null);
  const navigation = hooks.useAppNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
      try {
        console.log("Début de l'initialisation");
        await initConnection();
        console.log("Connexion initialisée");
        const subscriptions = await getSubscriptions({skus: [SUBSCRIPTION_SKU]})
        console.log("Subscriptions récupérées:", subscriptions);
        if (subscriptions.length === 0) {
          console.log("Aucun abonnement trouvé pour le SKU:", SUBSCRIPTION_SKU);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Erreur complète:', error);
        const errorMessage = (error as Error).message;
        Alert.alert('Erreur', `Une erreur est survenue: ${errorMessage}`);
      }
    };
  
    init();
  
    return () => {
      endConnection();
    }
  }, [])
}

I've already tried the following:

Double-checking the subscription ID in App Store Connect
Verifying that my app's bundle ID matches the one in App Store Connect
Ensuring that my Apple developer account has the necessary agreements signed
Waiting for 24 hours after creating the subscription in case of any delay

Questions:

What could be causing the subscription not to be detected?
Are there any specific configuration steps I might have missed?
How can I troubleshoot this issue further?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
